# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: java, email

The program attempts to send e-mail but throws a run time **exception:AuthenticationFailedException**.I entered username & pwd corect. Please tell me the appropriate solutions of it..Thanks

```
   import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMailTLS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "test@gmail.com";
        final String password = "test1234";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("test@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("testing@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

To be noted,I have already gone through the other solution regarding this in stack overflow but none of the solution served my purpose.That's why I am posting this question. Can anyone provide any suitable solution to this???

Comment: Probably you are providing wrong email id or password.. Please post the code if possible..

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: No, I provided correct email & pwd..however i m posting code here..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 session.setDebug(true);
```

before your `try{`, restart and look at the output.

As you're trying to send through gmail: You have to explicitly **allow** *unsafe* connections to use your gmail account. There's a link in the error message that contains more information.